# How to format form fields for django comments?

Tags: django, formatting, django-forms, styling, django-comments

I am using a form which is generated for me by django. I'm using this as a comment form after a post in my blog.

Currently it renders fine but it's not nicely aligned. 
This is what I have. [image]
This is what I'd like. [image]

Thanks

*edit: This is the result when I user {{ form.as_table }}*

[image]

Comment: How do you render your form in the template?

Comment: Currently it's all automatic. I haven't specified anything. If I create a form.html file in my templates/comments dir and use {{ form.as_p }} then it renders out the hidden field. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting my solution hoping it'll help someone else oneday.
I knew that you'd style the fields with css but wasn't sure how to assign the classes to each item. But if you take a look at the default template provided you'll notice that the error class is assigned to a field using an if statement within a foreach loop that automatically generates each field within your form.
*i.e.*

```
{% for field in form %}    
< p{% if field.errors %} 
    class="error"
{% endif %}
    {{ field.label_tag }}<'/' p> 
{% endfor %}
```

So I added onto this functionality.

```
< p{% if field.errors %} 
    class="error"
{% endif %}
{% ifequal field.name "honeypot" %} 
    id="hide"
{% else %}
     id="left"
{% endifequal %}>
    {{ field.label_tag }}<'/' p>
```

my css being

```
#hide{
    display:none;

}

#left{
    width: 200px;
    text-align: left;

}

#right{
    width: 300px;
    text-align: left;

}
```

Now that you can set your classes you can easily setup your classes or id within your css file. This is for the comments.
If you're using a {{ form.as_p }} or {{ form.as_table }} to generate your form then you just set a general form class within your css to style it.
*i.e.*

```
form {
width: 350px;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #270644;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I know it's a little late, but for everybody else you can try this

```
<table>
{{ form.as_table }}
</table>
```

It fixes the annoying formatting problem, and looks decent.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Customizing the form template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates). This is one possible solution.

Maybe you can simply use CSS to style your form and [render the form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#ref-forms-api-outputting-html) as you like. (i.e *as_table()*).

Comment: If I use {{form.as_table}} then it renders all the fields and headers and doesn't line them up nicely. If I user {{ form.as_p }} then I get the same result as you see above except that with both of these options I get the hidden field rendered too.

Comment: i'll look deeper into that documentation but if you come across any examples please let me know. Would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Using the default `{% render_comment_form for app.model %}` will generate:

```
<p>
      <label for="id_name">Name</label> 
      <input id="id_name" type="text" name="name" maxlength="50">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="id_email">Email address</label> 
      <input type="text" name="email" id="id_email">

</p>
... etc
```

Therefore, you can target `label` in your CSS stylesheet using:

```
label {
  width: 15%;
}
```

Comment: This is not good when you resize the page ( shrink ).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches as detailed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110378/change-the-width-of-form-elements-created-with-modelform-in-django), however, I found that sometimes widget attributes may not work the way you wanted.

**Still, the best and easy way is to use CSS:**

Render your page that contains the form fields and do some inspection (right click>inspect or F12 on Chrome for example) to know what html tags your form generates when rendered. Then you can write your CSS easily.

You have `input` and `textarea` fields in your form so your CSS will be:

```
input, textarea{
    width:350px;
}
```

Don't forget to call for your CSS file at the top of your html template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles/form.css' %}">
```

Here is a snapshot of what I have for my own form:

[image]