# Django Form alignment

Tags: django-templates

I have created a Form but becuase of the alignment problem I try to align myself in my template,

Forms.py

```
class VolunteerForm(forms.ModelForm):
        volposition = forms.CharField(label="Volunteer Position")
        roledesc = forms.CharField(label="Role Description")
        noofhours = forms.IntegerField(label="Time requirements")
        Qualreqt  = forms.CharField(label="Qualifications and Requirements")


        class Meta:
            model = Volunteer
```

views.py

```
def volunteer_page(request):
        #import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = VolunteerForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                f = form.save(commit=False)
                f.save()
                message = "Position added"
                return HttpResponseRedirect('.')
        else:
            form = VolunteerForm()
        variable = RequestContext(request,{'form':form})
        return render_to_response('registration/volunteer.html',variable)
```

Volunteer.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}User Registration{% endblock %}
{% block head %}User Registration{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<form method="post" action".">
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
     <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.volposition.errors }}
        <th><label for="id_volposition">Volunteer Position</label></th>
        <th>{{ form.volposition }}<maxlength="100"></th>
    </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.roledesc.errors }}
        <th><label for="id_roledesc">Role Description:</label></th>
        <th>{{ form.roledesc }}</th>
    </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.noofhours.errors }}
        <th><label for="id_noofhours">Number of Hours:</label></th>
        <th>{{ form.noofhours }}</th>
    </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.qualreqt.errors }}
        <th><label for="id_qualreqt">Qualification and Requirements</label></th>
        <th>{{ form.Qualreqt }}</th>
    </div>
    </tr>   
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="register" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

The role description and qualifications/requirements should have a much bigger text area compared to the html generated by this page

What would be my changes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the width of form elements created with ModelForm in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110378/change-the-width-of-form-elements-created-with-modelform-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

Well you could define the css attributes in Django...

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs

Or you could simply write the css manually... right click and view source if you're unsure what the id's of your html elements are

Comment: This link is not explaining how one can change CSS attributes, but widget attributes, which is something different, however by changing widget attributes one can change the alignment of the django form fields