# Django: customize table preferences using show_table_form

Tags: django, django-forms

i'm new to Django and i search how i can change the table preferences (especially td width) by using show_table_form?

In the html page i use `{% show_table_form db_form %}`. `db-form` is a `forms.ModelForm` with overrided labels. The labels are so long and i dont wanna break the lines hardcoded, so i wanna set the td widths to force automatically linebreaks.

Comment: I edited my first post. I hope now it's more understandable.

Comment: `show_table_form` is not a standard Django template tag.  Are you using the `load` tag to import custom functionality?  Or do you pearhaps mean `{{db_form.as_table}}`?

Comment: yes, i do use {% load tags_form %}. Is there a possibility by dont using it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set each fields attributes from your form class. You may want to check out [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/110414/1257959)