# Specifying Django widget attribute in ModelForm rather than as HTML <style>

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, widget

I have a Django input slider defined as follows:

#widgets.py

```
from django.forms.widgets import NumberInput
class RangeInput(NumberInput):
    input_type = 'range'
```

#forms.py

```
from polls.widgets import RangeInput
class VoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        #model = CC_Responses
        model = CC_Resp_NoFK
        fields = ['Person_ID', 'Test_date', 'Response_value']
        # following added from SliderModelForm
        widgets ={
            'Response_value':RangeInput
        }
```

which is “processed” by the view

```
def p2vote(request,q_id): 

    CC_question = get_object_or_404(CC_Questions, pk=q_id)
    #
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VoteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            item = form.save(commit=False)
            item.Q_ID = q_id
            item.save()
            return redirect('/polls/p2')
    else:
        formV = VoteForm()
    return render(request, 'pollapp2/vote.html', {'var_name':CC_question,'form' : VoteForm()})
```

and in the template I have the inline CSS

```
<style>
    /* Following CSS is used by the input slider (range) since Django assigns id value of id_Response_value */
    /*See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110378/change-the-width-of-form-elements-created-with-modelform-in-django */
    #id_Response_value{width:300px;} 
</style>
```

which is associated with the slider/range

```
<label for="Response_value">Response value</label>
{% render_field form.Response_value rows="1" class="form-control" %}
```

I obtained id_Response_value by looking at the source of the rendered HTML in the browser – I guess I could explicitly set an ID. All the above works exactly as I want. I can control the width of the range slider using CSS.

Now, I believe, inline CSS is a “bad thing”, so as a step to improve my code I’m trying to associate the attribute “more directly” with the slider.

In Django documentation in the section: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

there is the following example:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea
from myapp.models import Author

class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('name', 'title', 'birth_date')
        widgets = {
            'name': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20}),
        }
```

The dictionary attrs created looks like it has CSS “stuff” in it, so I coded in widgets in the model form in forms.py

```
from polls.widgets import RangeInput
class VoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CC_Resp_NoFK
        fields = ['Person_ID', 'Test_date', 'Response_value']
        widgets ={
            'Response_value':RangeInput(attrs={'width': '1000px'}),
        }
```

I tried both:

```
attrs={'width': '1000px'}
```

and

```
attrs={'width': 1000}
```

Neither changed the width of the range slider. Is what I am doing possible in the (model)form? Have I just got a problem with what I am coding in attrs?

I may have misunderstood but I see something like the following promoted as what needs to go in the ModelForm

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) # Call to ModelForm constructor
    self.fields['long_desc'].widget.attrs['cols'] = 10
    self.fields['long_desc'].widget.attrs['rows'] = 20
```

No. Really? To change the attributes?

Comment: the `attrs` adds HTML attributes - if you want to define the width using `attrs` you will need to use a `style` attribute: `attrs={'style': 'width: 1000px'}`. More info here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style.asp

Comment: Also it might be better to add something like `attrs={'class': 'my_custom_class'}` which will set a class for the widget, and you can then style the class using CSS

Comment: @iri I will try both.