# How to change the size of UserCreationForm?

Tags: python, django

I want to modify the weight of the fields in UserCreationForm. How is that possible?

```py
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField( widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "class": "input",
        "type": "text",
        "placeholder": "Username",
    }) )

    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "class": "input",
        "type": "email",
        "placeholder": "Email"
    }))

    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "class": "input",
        "type": "password",
        "placeholder": "Password"
    }))

    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "class": "input",
        "type": "password",
        "placeholder": "Password"
    }))


    class Meta:
        model= User
        fields = [
            "username", "email", "password1", "password2"
        ]
```

I want to modify the size of the fields: Username, Email, Password 1, and Password 2

More precisely, I want the fields longer. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: The [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs) explains how to set  `size`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the width of form elements created with ModelForm in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110378/change-the-width-of-form-elements-created-with-modelform-in-django)

Comment: See also the `attrs={'size':'20'}` setting in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910169/resize-fields-in-django-admin/72847861#72847861